# NTFS-3G: All files are an "unsupported reparse point"

Tags: filesystems, mount, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I just connected my NTFS HDD to my homeserver and I have an odd problem.
EVERY file on the HDD is displayed as an "unsupported reparse point" in `ls -lsa`

I tried mounting with different permissions and even did an `ntfsfix`, but no workey...

When i plug the drive into my Windows machine everything works flawlessly, so it cannot be a corrupt Filesystem.

I cannot access any files because of this :/

Any Ideas?

The output looks like this:

```
xendo@CloudKicker:/mnt/4t$ ls -lsa
total 2126
  40 drwxrwxrwx 1 root root   40960 May 15 14:20 .
   4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 May 15 15:38 ..
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 2 root root      26 Jan  8  2014 file.txt -> unsupported reparse point
...
```

My fstab entry is:

```
/dev/disk/by-partuuid/1b7eed2e-32c0-4221-82dd-e0f0a16b910f /mnt/4t ntfs-3g defaults,auto,umask=000,allow_others 0 0
```

ntfs-3g verision is: `ntfs-3g 2014.2.15AR.3 integrated FUSE 28`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I do not have a solution, but I think I found the cause.

I can still BROWSE my HDD via Windows, but i cannot access any files, because they are reported with 0 bytes on disk. So either my file-system is corrupt, or I just invented the most efficient compression... (I do not think it is the latter ;) )

I do not know if it was caused by ntfs-3g or not, but this is definitely why I get those "errors". (Technically correct description of what is going on.)

Screenshot of a Windows properties window:

[image: my file-system got corrupt up somehow]

Thanks for your comments anyways!